# Why is "でしょう" the norm in weather forecasts?

Tags: usage

In weather forecasts on the radio or on TV, I frequently notice the announcers suddenly starting to add "でしょう" to almost all their sentences. Now I know this is used to indicate uncertainty, which seems understandable given that weather forecasts *are* uncertain. However, I would say such constructions would be considered quite unusual in other languages (at least in Western European languages it is), in which the (majority of) sentences do not imply uncertainty, at least not explicitly.

Is this a phenomenon occurring only in Japanese? Is it simply by custom, that is,  something someone started doing at some point and simply became the norm? Or is there some more important (cultural or linguistical?) reason behind explicitly using "でしょう" in such contexts?

Comment: Consider *It **will** rain tomorrow* versus *It rains tomorrow*, with the presence or absense of the modal auxiliary *will*.